# Why is express.js public folder not working over the internet?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

My app.js code that runs with node on port 3000 which is then linked through Nginx to go public

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

In the public folder, there is a test.html file. When I try accessing this file locally using http://localhost:3000/test.html, it works! However, when I put the servers IP/test.html, I get an Nginx 404 page. Please explain!

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with your node.js code. You need to debug your Nginx config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Nginx config default file I had to remove the `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` line of code.